# A Julia iterator error

Tags: julia

I am looking at an iterator example from http://lostella.github.io/blog/2018/07/25/iterative-methods-done-right and have a question. The following works and produces Fibonacci numbers up to 13:

```
iterate(f::FibonacciIterable) = f.s0, (f.s0, f.s1)
iterate(f::FibonacciIterable, state) = state[2], (state[2], state[1] + state[2])

for f in FibonacciIterable(0, 1)
    print("$f ")
    if f > 10 println(); break end
end
```

I am trying to replace the two `iterate` functions with one, configured with a default value:

```
iterate(f::FibonacciIterable, state = (f.s0, (f.s0, f.s1)) ) = (state[2], state[1] + state[2])
```

Running this code produces:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching +(::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Any, !Matched::Any...) at operators.jl:502
  +(::T<:Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}, !Matched::T<:Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}) where T<:Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8} at int.jl:53
  +(::Union{Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8}, !Matched::BigInt) at gmp.jl:456
```

**Note**: using Julia 1.0

**Commenting here on answer by Bogumił Kamiński for formating and extra space**

Thank you Bogumił - but I am still having a hard time bulding a mental model on how this works. First of all the following also
produces the expected output:

```
iterate(iter::FibonacciIterable, state=(iter.s1, iter.s0)) = state[2], (state[2], sum(state))
```

The documentation says:

```
iterate(iter [, state]) -> Union{Nothing, Tuple{Any, Any}}

Advance the iterator to obtain the next element. If no elements remain, nothing should be returned. 
Otherwise, a 2-tuple of the next element and the new iteration state should be returned.
```

The way I read this, the first call to this version of `iterate` will return `iter.s1` and set up the next state 
to be `iter.s0`. So the output from the first call should be `1` and the next invocation of `iterate` should fail
as there is no such thing as `state[2]`. Obviously this is not what is happening as the first value  is `0` and the calculation proceeds without errors. Can you point out where my logic goes wrong?

**Comment 2**

Right - that helped:

```
julia> iterate(FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3)))
(2, (2, 3))
```

I assumed that the parameter named `state` and the return type of `iterate` (which I thought of as the next state) are of the same type.

As you pointed out that is not the case as the type of `state` parameter is `Tuple{I,I}` but the type of the return value is `Tuple{I, Tuple{I,I}}` (actually `Union{Nothing, Tuple{I, Tuple{I,I}}}` but never mind that) where the "inner" tuple is the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass only state, so a `Tuple{I, I} where {I}` not `Tuple{I, Tuple{I, I}} where {I}`. In this case you also have to go back one step in Fibonacci sequence to get a correct first step (i.e. value stored in `iter.s0`).

Therefore the way you can define your `iterate` function is:

```
iterate(iter::FibonacciIterable, state=(iter.s1-iter.s0, iter.s0)) =
    state[2], (state[2], sum(state))
```

And now all works as expected:

```
julia> for F in FibonacciIterable(BigInt(0), BigInt(1))
           println(F)
           F > 10 && break
       end
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

**EDIT**: Referring to your additional question.

If you change the definition to:

```
iterate(iter::FibonacciIterable, state=(iter.s1, iter.s0)) = state[2],
        (state[2], sum(state))
```

the iteration will be incorrect. Consider this example when using your definition:

```
julia> for F in FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3))
                  println(F)
                             F > 10 && break
                                    end
2
5
7
12
```

And we clearly see that something goes wrong.

In order to understand this case you have to build a mental model what is iterator state in our exercise. It is a tuple of the following form `(fibonacci(n), fibonacci(n+1)` i.e. first goes element `n` and the second is element `n+1`.

Now I am switching to my definition:

```
iterate(iter::FibonacciIterable, state=(iter.s1-iter.s0, iter.s0)) =
        state[2], (state[2], sum(state))
```

Let us check what happens when we run those lines:

```
julia> iterate(FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3)))
(2, (2, 3))

julia> iterate(FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3)), (2, 3))
(3, (3, 5))

julia> iterate(FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3)), (3, 5))
(5, (5, 8))
```

In the first line `iterate` tells you that the first element is `2` and state to use in the next iteration is `(2,3)`. So in the second line we use this state to get the next iteration: value `3` and next state `(3,5)`. We go on using this new state to obtain the next value `5` and next state `(5,8)`.

I guess in this example the confusion is that state is a tuple but also what `iterate` returns is a tuple. Probably a more didactic approach could be to define a new iteration state type:

```
struct FiboState{I}
    a::I
    b::I
end
```

and the following definition of `iterate`:

```
iterate(iter::FibonacciIterable, state=FiboState(iter.s1-iter.s0, iter.s0)) =
        state.b, FiboState(state.b, state.a+state.b)
```

and now we clearly see what is going on:

```
julia> iterate(FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3)))
(2, FiboState{BigInt}(2, 3))

julia> iterate(FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3)), FiboState{BigInt}(2, 3))
(3, FiboState{BigInt}(3, 5))

julia> iterate(FibonacciIterable(BigInt(2), BigInt(3)), FiboState{BigInt}(3, 5))
(5, FiboState{BigInt}(5, 8))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Commenting in the question for formating and extra space

Comment: I have added an additional explanation. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks - commenting again in the question for formating and extra space